# Nested quotes not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter, escaping

I'm trying to use the card validator ([Twitter validator](http://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)) in twitter. I have my code in the variable called content all my other code is working, but the twitter meta tags. I have the quotes of the tags like \" but when I do this the twitter validator doesn't show my card properly.

If I remove the \ then the rest of my code doesn't work properly. Is there a way to escape the quote so that the twitter card validator will accept it and read the meta tags.

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Image link: <input type="text" id="img">
        Content: <input type="text" id="content">
        <button onclick="makePage()">click</button>
        <script src="makePage.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            var img = document.getElementById("img").value;
            var content = document.getElementById("content").value;   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code. The html is in the content variable.

```
function makePage(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
}
var content = '<html><head></head><body><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes"><meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir"><meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral"><meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here."><meta name="twitter:image" content=""></body></html>';
xmlhttp.open("GET","makePage.php?content=" + content,true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

My PHP code (I'm dynamically making pages):

```
<?php
    $content = $_GET["content"];
    $file = "" . uniqid() . ".html";
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
    echo $file;
?>
```

The error the Twitter validator is giving:

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully

INFO:  8 metatags were found

WARN:  Not whitelisted
```

I know that it says 'Not whitelisted', but my website is white listed (it works on the main page). I'm sure this is being caused due to the nested quotes.

Comment: Isn't simpler using single quote instead the double ones? `var content = '<html><head></head><body><meta name="twitter:card"...`

Comment: Yeah, that does make it easier, \" automatically gets added to the code now. But, it still doesn't work when I put the URL in the validator. The twitter validator is still not reading it correctly because of the \".

Comment: I don't know what validator you refer to, please add the relevant code.

Comment: I've mentioned that it's the Twitter validator I'm referring to.

Comment: So probably this https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator and what url are you trying to put there? Can you add the code you are using?

Comment: Yes that one, I'm trying to put this url: http://ahansabharwal.com/55ec0df88d7d1.html                                                If you try http://ahansabharwal.com/ it works. The nested quotes are causing the problem.

Comment: You are returning escaped double quotes like this `meta name=\"twitter:card\"` I think the problem could be that

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. But I need that, I'm using the URL in my PHP code. Is there a way to do the same, which the validator will accept. I've added a bit more to my Javascript.

Comment: I've added my PHP and HTML code.

Comment: It works for me, it generates an html file with correct quotes that's valid in the validator

Comment: Can you please add your content string?

Comment: I added the complete JS code I used. PHP code is the same.

Comment: Strange. Can you please check if the source code of the website you create is exactly the same as this: view-source:http://ahansabharwal.com/55ec1b36d4702.html. If it's the same then there must be a problem with the white listing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL Encode your query string `content` so the `xmlhttp.open` should be:

```
var content = '<html><head></head><body><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes"><meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir"><meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral"><meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here."><meta name="twitter:image" content=""></body></html>';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.michelem.org/ddd.php?content=" + encodeURIComponent(content), true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: I've added my PHP code. When I add this and put normal quotes ("<html>...")  around my var content it doesn't work (my php code doesn't execute) but when I put single quotes ('<html>...') it still adds \" to all the quotes.